# Mysql, PHP and UTC_TIMESTAMP()

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I know there's a hundred questions on here about this topic, but I've read them all and still am not getting it.

I'm storing the date I last hit an API in a settings table using `UTC_TIMESTAMP()`. The column type is a mysql `timestamp`:

```
UPDATE settings SET last_pull = UTC_TIMESTAMP();
```

When I select this from mysql I get the following:

```
mysql> select last_pull from settings;
+---------------------+
| last_pull           |
+---------------------+
| 2015-06-30 23:05:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Seems clear, since I'm on Pacific time, that UTC time is 8 hours ahead. Therefore it was 16:05:00 local time when I created that record. (It was actually 16:05 local time-- I was there!)

What's confusing me is that when I pull the data back out of the DB, according to every answer on here, I should be able to use the default PHP `date` or `datetime` functions, and assuming I have my timezone properly set, I should get the local time from that timestamp (eg. `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $last_pull_value)` should return `2015-06-30 16:05:00`).

Is this assumption incorrect? I've verified my timezones for linux and PHP are correct, and that mysql is properly set as well.

Yet when I do

```
$last_pull = new DateTime();
$last_pull->setTimestamp($row['last_pull']);                

var_dump($last_pull->format("c"));
```

it returns:

```
"2015-06-30 23:05:00"
```

So then I explicitly set the timezone:

```
$last_pull = new DateTime();
$last_pull->setTimestamp($row['last_pull']);    
$last_pull->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));           

var_dump($last_pull->format("c"));
```

And it returns the exact same thing (makes sense if the default TZ was correct to begin with).

```
"2015-06-30 23:05:00"
```

My question is how do I get the *local* time when the API last pulled? Why won't the `datetime` function return 16:05:00?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the timezone for your DateTime object on initialisation, It will work as you expect.

```
$last_pull = new DateTime('2015-06-30 23:05:00', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
var_dump($last_pull->format("c")); //string(25) "2015-06-30T23:05:00+00:00"
$last_pull->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
var_dump($last_pull->format("c")); //string(25) "2015-06-30T16:05:00-07:00"
```

The DateTime object's documentation notes that the default timezone used for a new date time object is your current timezone - http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php